# Unable to understand space requirements with figure tag HTML5

Tags: css, html, layout, space, figure

I am working on a page using HTML5 that needs to use 4 figure tags placed adjacent to each other in a horizontal line. Each figure tag comprises of an image which holds an icon 80X80px and underneath the image is a caption.

It looks something like below:
[image]

**Problem:** Using developer tools, when I hover over the figure tag, it shows the dimensions as 80px x 120 px which is fine taking the combination of icon+caption into account. However, what it's actually doing while rendering can be seen in the snapshot. It's occupying some additional space (the width is being shows as 80px but it's using more than that!) which pushes the adjacent figure further to the right than it needs to be. The code snippet looks like as under:

```
          <div id="figureIcons">
                <a href="" class="extLinks" target="_blank">
                    <figure class="icons">
                        <img class="linksIcons" src="icons/chrome_link.png" title="Website">
                        <figcaption><b>HomePage</b><br />(Website)</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </a>

                <a href="" class="extLinks" target="_blank">
                    <figure class="icons">
                        <img class="linksIcons" src="icons/linkedin_link.png" title="LinkedIn Profile">
                        <figcaption><b>Profile</b><br />(LinkedIn)</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </a>
         </div>
```

The only CSS used for the above arrangement:

```
figure.icons
{
    position:relative; 
    float:left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}
```

The above is the only css used relevant to the problem. Other classes/IDs assigned have not been used yet in the stylesheet.

Where am I going wrong? How do I fix this? I need to place 4 such figures next to each other. Please help, Thanks!

Comment: What do the classes look like? i.e. `figureIcons`, `extLinks`, `icons`, `linksIcons`.

Answer (score 0):

A `<figure>` has margins by default, so if you want its right and bottom margin to be 0, you must specify them explicitly in the stylesheet.

In other words, replace

```
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 1px;
```

by

```
margin:5px 0 0 1px;
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/d77hV/1/).

And the reason why the Inspector doesn't add the margin to the width when you look at the size, is that technically the margins are not part of the element; they're on the outside. (If you were to give it a padding, that would be added to the width.)